# Fourier series t+1

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I could use some help with the basic problem of finding the fourier series of the $2\pi$-periodic function $f(t) = t+1$, for $-\pi < t < \pi$.

Edit: I removed my calculations, since they were based on the fact that it was an odd function. $f(t)$ is neither an odd or an even function.

Comment: Show us your calculation!  Note: $t+1$ is not an odd function.

Comment: Hi, how come t+1 is not an odd function? Also, does that mean that it is an even function?

Comment: I have updated my post with my calculations for $b_n$

Comment: I would say $b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dots$ instead

Comment: A function is "odd" if and only if f(-x)= -f(x) and "even" if and only if f(-x)= f(x).  The names come from the fact that polynomials that have only **odd** powers, such as x^3+ 3x, are "odd" functions and polynomials that have only **even** powers, such as x^2+ 1, are "even" functions. But there are many functions that are **neither** even nor odd and this is one of them: if f(t)= t+ 1 then f(1)= 1+ 1= 2 while f(-1)= -1+ 1= 0, neither "1" nor "-1".  In fact, in a very precise sense, *almost all* functions are neither even nore odd.

Comment: For an odd function, we need $f(-t)=-f(t)$.  But $(-t+1) \ne -(t+1)$

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! So, do I need to calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$ separate (since none of them is equal to zero), and then add them together, or is there another, simpler way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The function $1$ has a simple Fourier series -- it is $1$. That allows you to reduce to an odd function $f(t)$ because the Fourier series of $1+t$ is the Fourier series of $1$ plus the Fourier series of $t$. For $t$,
$$
  t  \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}u\sin(nu)\right]\sin(nu)du
$$
And,
\begin{align}
   \int u\sin(nu)du&=-u\frac{\cos(nu)}{n}+\int\frac{\cos(nu)}{n}du \\
   &=-u\frac{\cos(nu)}{n}+\frac{\sin(nu)}{n^2}+C
\end{align}
That gives coefficients
\begin{align}
    \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}u\sin(nu)du&=\left.\frac{2}{\pi}\left[-u\frac{\cos(nu)}{n}+\frac{\sin(nu)}{n^2}\right]\right|_{0}^{\pi} \\
   &=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[-\pi\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\right]=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
\end{align}
So your Fourier series for $f(t)=1+t$ is
$$
      f(t) \sim 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx).
$$